# display json data into sections depends on year released in table view

Tags: ios, swift

I am reading JSON file that has 20 elements to table view using swift 4. the elements are phone names and year of release such that (year, name). now, I am reading them all successfully to the table view. but how I do read the names into sections related to their year of release. for example, any phone name that released in 2005 will be in 2005 section.

```
JSON sample :
{
"phones" : [

    {
      "year": "2005",
      "cuisine": "Iphone 5"

    },{.....}
}
```

Comment: I am assuming that in your json you do not have a record of number of years? and there can be multiple phones released in same year.right?

Comment: Look at [Dictionary(grouping:by:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2995342-init)

Comment: Yes,  there no record of number of years

Answer (score 0):

When you parsed json into array of models, you need to filter them by years. Each group of filtered models would be a section in your table view.